# Facebook app permission shows only when link is opened in new tab on first time

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've created an Fb app on PHP which shows basic data like user name & profile picture. But it does not show on the first time, as the SDK generates the login button the user must open that link in a new tab/window to give permission to the app. If the user just clicks on the link nothing happens but works if opened in a new tab.
I've used FB PHP SDK V 2

Link of the app
https://apps.facebook.com/520211878109855/

The following message was shown in Firefox console

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=520211878109855&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fsou1989-test3.herokuapp.com%2Findex.php&state=27d7a68bc9005ab1f7c90ff92f443353&scope=email%2Coffline_access%2Cpublish_stream%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_location%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_about_me%2Cuser_hometown does not permit framing.
```

Comment: Why don't you open the auth dialog in a popup, or use the JS SDK login dialog?

Comment: @Igy how to do so, plz help !

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: I solved the problem using the login button with target="_top"